# WPF element height binding lost after animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, grid

In my example app, I have a inner grid's height binded to the main grid's height. When I maximise and minimise the window, their heights are the same. after I execute an animation that changes the inner grid's height from 100 to binding the main grid's height again, the binding is lost. This is evident because when I maximise the window, the inner grids height remains the same while the main grid's height changes to fit the fill height of the window

Why is this and how can I fix it so the inner grid retains the main grid's height after I've set it back to that after an animation.

Example app:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkSlider" x:Name="ShrinkSlider"
                Completed="ShrinkSlider_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="gridSlider"
            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
            From="100"
            To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}"
            Duration="00:00:00.5" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandSlider" x:Name="ExpandSlider"
                Completed="ExpandSlider_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="gridSlider"
            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
            From="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}"
            To="100"
            Duration="00:00:00.5" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click"
                  SourceName="btnShrink">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bsbShrinkSlider"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkSlider}" />
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click"
                  SourceName="btnExpand">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bsbExpandSlider"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpandSlider}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid x:Name="gridSlider"
          Background="#1f1f1f"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}">
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Shrink"
                x:Name="btnShrink"
            Height="20"
                Click="BtnShrink_Click" />
        <Button Content="Expand"
                x:Name="btnExpand"
            Height="20"
                Click="BtnExpand_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is what your code will do.
When the window opens the inner grid (gridSlider) will be same height as the outer grid (gridMain). 
Suppose you open and maximize the window, Once you hit Expand the animation  will reduce the height of the gridSlider to 100px. In this case the gridSlider will be 100px from the top (as you have set VerticalAlignment).

Click on Shrink and it will take gridSlider back from 100 pixel to full length of gridMain. And I think this is exactly what you have coded, is this not the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: After executing the expand animation, if I maximise the window, the inner grid's height doesn't update its height to the main grid. The binding appears to have broken @ArifEqbal

Comment: And that's exactly what you have asked it to do....break the binding....look at your code for expand animation, you are asking gridSlider to change its height from the binding to a fixed 100px height.

Comment: @ArifEqbal I got shrink and expand storyboards the wrong way around there. Expand was supposed to be changing the height from 100 to "{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}". This didn't reset the binding though. I've come up with a solution however if you see my answer. If you know a more graceful way of doing it then let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. I needed to set Storyboard FillBehaviour = "Stop"

Then I needed to recreate the binding on the Storyboard Completed event:

```
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = gridMain;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Grid.ActualHeightProperty);
        gridSlider.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, binding);
```

Here is the full code amended:

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkSlider" x:Name="ShrinkSlider"
                Completed="ShrinkSlider_Completed"
                FillBehavior="Stop">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="gridSlider"
            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
            From="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}"
            To="100"
            Duration="00:00:00.5" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandSlider" x:Name="ExpandSlider"
                Completed="ExpandSlider_Completed"
                FillBehavior="Stop">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="gridSlider"
            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
            From="100"
            To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}"
            Duration="00:00:00.5" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click"
                  SourceName="btnShrink">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bsbShrinkSlider"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkSlider}" />
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click"
                  SourceName="btnExpand">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bsbExpandSlider"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpandSlider}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid x:Name="gridSlider"
          Background="#1f1f1f"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridMain}">
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Shrink"
                x:Name="btnShrink"
            Height="20" />
        <Button Content="Expand"
                x:Name="btnExpand"
            Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
private void ShrinkSlider_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridSlider.Height = 100;
    }

    private void ExpandSlider_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = gridMain;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Grid.ActualHeightProperty);
        gridSlider.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, binding);
    }
```